# Как сделать так чтобы дискорд бот реагировал на пинг?

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу сделать так чтобы например , когда пингуешь бота в дискорде - тот отправил сообщение по типу "пропиши .ban"

Comment: Куда он должен отправить это сообщение?

Comment: в тот же канал где его пинганули

Comment: Что-то я не понимаю. Под пингом Вы имеете в виду утилиту ping в классическом понимании или что-то другое?

Comment: Ping - это функционал дискорда, который позволяет послать запрос к боту, например что бы проверить его работоспособность. Это не имеет никакого отношения к этой утилите

Answer (score 1):

Открываем офф [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
Они приводят пример вот такого кода:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong!\n Latency {0}'.format(round(bot.latency, 1)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно что бы он отвечал что вы хотите необходимо:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Пропиши .ban")
```

Comment: Кавычку надо закрыть по идее

Comment: Закрыл, спасибо

Comment: Должны быть однотипные кавычки :) Либо только `'`, либо только `"`

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if ("<@!id бота>" in message.content):
        await message.channel.send('пропиши .ban')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ну хоть границу слова после idнадо проверять что ли...